# Tracking Outbound Links - How to filter out javascript:; Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am tracking all outbound clicks with a google tag manager trigger which includes all links which are not containing my domain url. Now ive got a problem with NextGEN Wordpress Gallery. Whenever someone clicks on an image and the image opens in lightview ive got an Outbound Link event with Label javascript:; (label is normally the page url). How can i filter out these javascript-events?

Thx for your help and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger in GTM, just add a new 'Fire On' condition with the following values:

[image: GTM Trigger Filter]

These condition's are 'AND-ed' so all must be true for the trigger to fire and hence this will filter out (at source) any of these javascript urls.

Comment: OK, you're going to have to help me out here though - more information required!  What 'Fire on' conditions do you have applied to your trigger?  Anything you think might be pertinent?

Comment: Im still testing... sorry maybe i was a bit tooo fast. I will give you more information soon. Cant reproduce the problem acutally...